# Socket answering 302 if HTTP and forwarding to another socket if not (Python if possible)

Tags: python, sockets

Due to firewall restriction, I have to "share" the 80/tcp port on a machine.
I try to achieve this :
- Python script (or xinetd using a python script) listening on port 80
- Custom (binary language) service listening on port 5000
- When a user try to connect to the port 80 via http browser, it answers code 301 Moved permanently (to https://...)
- When a program tries to connect to port 80, it forwards to port 5000, and then forwards answer to program.

It seems simple but I do not manage to do it.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

def file_put_contents(filename, mode, data):
  file = open(filename, mode)
  file.write(data)
  file.close()

pipe = ??
for line in sys.stdin:
if 'GET /' in line:
  print 'HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently';
  print 'Location: http://www.zyve.com';
else:
  file_put_contents(pipe, 'a+', line)
  sys.exit(0)
```

I am new to python, sorry.
Have a nice day,

Comment: Is your indentation done correctly?

Comment: Hello yes but the code is not good

Comment: Related: [Python port forwarding/multiplexing server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1874331/python-port-forwarding-multiplexing-server)